# Linux heap - is doing a ton of new/deletes okay or does the heap become badly fragmented?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, http-headers, heap-memory

I'm not familiar with how the Linux heap is allocated.

I'm calling malloc()/free() many many times a second, always with the same sizes (there are about 10 structs, each fixed size).  Aside from init time, none of my memory remains allocated for long periods of time.

Is this considered poor form with the standard heaps?  (I'm sure someone will ask 'what heap are you using?' - 'Ugh.  The standard static heap' ..meaning I'm unsure.)

Should I instead use a free list or does the heap tolerate lots of the same allocations.  I'm trying to balance readability with performance.

Any tools to help me measure?

Comment: If you share your code we might give you optimization tips.

Comment: Having all allocations require the same size sounds like an opportunity for a "pool" allocation scheme, which could potentially be faster, because it's simpler than a general-purpose allocator.

Comment: @Kerrek: On the other hand, allocating and freeing lots of identically-sized objects should be pretty fast with the glibc allocator.  R. is right, there is no reason to worry about this until after your profiler tells you to.  The only time I have ever seen "pools" help is in a multi-threaded application; the glibc allocator is not so hot when many threads are contending for the heap.

Comment: ptmalloc should actually perform pretty well with multiple threads contending for the heap as long as the allocation and free take place in the same thread. This is actually the whole point of ptmalloc. However I think the whole concept of tuning allocator performance with heuristics like this is a bit misguided, since allocator performance should not make a measurable difference in a well-designed application.

Comment: @R: In my experience, ptmalloc does not perform very well even when all of the threads free their own allocations.  tcmalloc's performance numbers back this up as well...  And for some applications, allocating lots of small objects is the most natural way to code.  (Especially allocating lots of small objects and then freeing them all at once.  Call it a "vector" or a "pool allocator"; it amounts to the same thing.)

Comment: tcmalloc rather cheats by doing things like never freeing any memory to the system and allocating *gigantic* bookkeeping structures. I hate to think how bloated/memory-hungry systems would be if every program were using tcmalloc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind has a special tool [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) for measuring memory usage. This should help to profile heap allocations.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, unless you have **measured** a problem with memory usage blowing up, don't even think about using a custom allocator. It's one of the worst forms of premature optimization.

At the same time, even if you do have a problem, a better solution than a custom allocator would be figuring out why you're allocating and freeing objects so much, and fixing the design issue that's causing it.

To address your specific question, glibc's allocator is based on the dlmalloc algorithm, which is near-optimal when it comes to fragmentation. The only way you'll get it to badly fragment memory is the unavoidable way: by allocating objects with radically different lifetimes in alternation, e.g. allocating a large number of objects but only freeing every other one. I think you'll have a hard time working out an allocation pattern that will give worse total memory usage than pools...

Comment: I voted this down b/c it's condescending and it seems as though 'R' didnt read my entire post before getting on the high horse.  the last paragraph is useful up until the point where he becomes condescending again and doesn't source his facts

---how do replies like this get voted up so high, they make stackoverflow full of cruft.   I wish 'R' didnt make the assumption that I was on a bad path but rather assumed I'm on a solid path and answered (or ignored) the questions being answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best performance optimization is to avoid heap allocation wherever it is possible (and reasonable). Whenever an object is stack allocated the compiler will just move the stack pointer up instead of trying to find a free spot or return the allocated memory to some free list.

How is the lifetime of your structures defined? If you can express your object lifetime by scoping then this would indeed increase performance.